# How to create dynamic element XML in Filemaker Pro advanced

Tags: xml, filemaker

I want to create XML with dynamic Element and attribute according to Database record in Filemaker advanced. As Filemaker generate fixed format XML.

Should it is possible? and How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you need a XSLT file to transform the FileMaker XML grammar into your XML. Once you have this file, you can tell FileMaker to use it during export. This is a fairly generic answer, of course, but so is the question :)

Comment: Thanks, will use XSLT to transform the grammar.